# File is Not marked as Executable?

Tags: ubuntu, installation, execution, ttlauncherview, ttlauncheritem

- I have been trying to install TLauncher on my Ubuntu pc which runs **23.04** OS. And while i have downloaded the jar file it is giving me the error of item not marked executable. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJeo3.png)

I tried some solutions from youtube to change security setting as well but there are no option to allow install or execute. Further solutions on the internet seem to have a permissions tab in properties and a checkbox for making it executable but unfortunately I am don't see any such option.[[[[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzWRU.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vqo5L.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BbgqR.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DgSmp.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3mzT.png)